# Write an Oracle PL/SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Requirement: one table present in both **flipflop** schema (like SR is the schema whose **flip flop** schema is *SR1 and SR2*).

In both schema, table has the same structure. Now I need to create a procedure which compares the two table's data, and if any data update happened, then that new/updated data would be inserted in another staging table.

Comment: You should have posted some more fine details about your tables, schema and the code you have written so far. Are these two schema on the same machine etc.

Comment: The "code you have written so far" is the most major part of what we would ask of you.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you create triggers for such cases, so that you don't have to compare the two tables on the two different databases. Create a Trigger on both the databases for both the tables. If a row is inserted, updated, delete from Table A in the schema SR1, the trigger of schema SR1 would perform the same action on Table A of database SR2 and vice versa.

Although you could do it with a PL SQL procedure, but it would require you to create a procedure and check the differences between the two tables yourself. You could then schedule a database job, which runs this procedure every 10-15 minutes to check the two tables.

However with both the approaches you are likely to get permission errors because you are using two different schema. Have a look at [this link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6386500346452721).

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
select f1, f2, f3, ...
from table_1
    minus
select f1, f2, f3, ...
from table_2;
```

or vice-versa.

In this case, you will have the differences between table_1 and table_2.
You can use the result of this select with a cursor, into a PLSQL code to insert in the staging table.